# PhD program application - CV (3+ pages) versus resume (1-2 pages) in the US

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, cv, research-undergraduate

I am applying to neurobiology Ph.D. programs in the US that focus on disease research.

I am seeking opinions on my personal situation regarding the decision to include either a resume (1-2 sides) OR a CV (multiple pages) in my graduate school application for the schools that don't provide me much space to write about research. I also want to know about whether or not I can include research experience blurbs in the CV.

Originally, after being told by most schools that allow up to 5 recommendation letters to only submit 3 and after being told not to upload anything in the "optional and additional uploads," I felt a resume would be better for my application. Less writing and easier to read for the admissions faculty. However, I know many Ph.D.students that have submitted CVs, and almost every school I'm applying to states that I can submit a CV.

I don't have that much to discuss, aside from 3 significant 2+ year teaching experiences as an undergraduate student and 3 research experiences (2 summer internships + home university research since I was a freshman). Unfortunately, I won't have a paper out for at least another year due to an ongoing study. I am also active in several clubs/honors societies. Thus, my current "resume" is 3.5 pages long. I could probably get it to 2 pages, **but this is where you come in.**

Would you suggest to expand even more, possibly elaborating more on my research experiences so that my CV is around 4-6 pages, or would you recommend to keep it as a brief resume? For the CV, can I include 4-5 sentence research descriptions after I list the knitty-gritty stuff (e.g. program, what I did in that research program in regard to career building, etc.)?

**The main reason I ask this is that I'm slowly starting to figure out some schools give me absolutely no room to discuss research experience.** For instance, Johns Hopkins allows me to write a single page personal statement while answering quite a few other large points; thus, elaborating on research is hard. Also, I just contacted Duke who had a similar case in their application, and the Ph.D. admissions advisor for neuroscience told me to include details about my research experiences in the CV or the optional supplemental uploader. Harvard told me not to utilize the optional supplemental uploader to further discuss my research, although they allow CV uploads.

Regardless, for some of these schools, I will need to at least include a few extra sentences about my research whether that be through the optional file uploader or a CV. Has anyone had this internal debate or has a strong opinion on the better option? Thank you!

Comment: You should still specify where you are, rather than just describing the documents, as it may affect the expection and hence the answer. Since you didn't even think of it, there's a strong chance that it's USA, but I wouldn't like to presume ;-)

Comment: Why do you assume that every application has to be identical to every other? Use what seems best for any given situation.

Comment: @Buffy I didn't mean to make my question sound as if I have to do everything the same at each school. Of course, each application is different. This question is more geared toward the many schools that I feel are not allowing me the space to discuss past research experiences (e.g. 1-page personal statements). I have no idea if admissions committees would be happy to read 5-6 page CVs when other students submit 1-2 page resumes.

Comment: Note that every applicant has the same restrictions. Do what you can within the bounds of each application.

Comment: What you are calling a "CV" sounds very bloated to me and not the ordinary use of the term "CV" in US academia.

Comment: The type of CV that I've been told can be used for graduate school, essentially a pre-mature "typical academia CV": https://wordvice.com/how-to-write-a-flawless-cv-curriculum-vitae-for-graduate-school/ and https://www.prepscholar.com/gre/blog/how-to-write-a-cv-for-graduate-school/

Comment: 4-6 pages is way too long for a grad school CV. Your 3.5 page resume sounds more like a CV.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the input. I was seeing ranges around 4-5, but I agree with keeping it at 3.5 pages.

Comment: You shouldn't be aiming for a particular page length. Those resources tell you what things should be in a CV. Most of an academic CV is publications, which you don't have - that's okay, but don't replace a lack of publications with a bloated CV containing extra stuff that doesn't belong.

Comment: Johns Hopkins says: "The one-page statement should include your motivations for pursuing a graduate degree in neuroscience at Johns Hopkins and should describe your scientific preparation and your long-term career goals. It should include a description of any research experiences you have pursued." - that's not 50 questions, and clearly they expect you to describe research experiences in 1 page with everything else. If you can't do that now, work on condensing your writing.

Comment: "Describe your scientific preparation and your long-term career goals. It should include a description of any research experiences you have pursued. The statement should enable the admissions committee to determine that you are committed to pursuing a PhD in neuroscience and understand what is needed to succeed in graduate school, you are intellectually engaged in science and your research, and that the program in neuroscience at Johns Hopkins is a good fit for your research and career interests. Please indicate faculty in the Neuroscience program whose work you find interesting."

Comment: That is a lot of material to write on but they're good topics. And my point is not that I can't condense it all into a page, but given that I have a page to describe everything, my single paragraph explaining 3 significant research experiences will be challenging. It's hard for me specifically because I know that I'm not giving them enough material to work with.

Answer (score 3):

In the United States, when applying to a PhD program, you should upload a CV, not a resume.

Your CV should not include any descriptive sentences.  The current custom is for CVs to be a list of facts, with no qualitative information.  Put the descriptions in your personal statements.

Comment: This is the same for the UK. What may be helpful would be to google something like "PhD student CV template" and look at the examples and, in particular, the subheadings that you should have in your CV.

Comment: Thank you both very much for the confirmation. I think this is a good approach. I never intended to put any descriptive sentences in my Ph.D. applicant CV, but after an admissions staff told me that he usually gets "everything he needs in regard to research experience" from a CV, I got a little worried and wondered if I was supposed to be including some sort of brief summary on myself/research experience. Turns out, that's definitely not what you want to do as I originally thought. Hopefully, he can pull enough from my title of presentation/skills listed in each experience, haha.