# An academic CV for PhD applicants

Tags: phd, application, cv, application-cover-letter

I'm looking at some academic CVs by PhDs and professors. The focus seems to be long list of talks, conferences, publications and teaching experiences. I have none of these things. Whhat I have now of any substance is (i) 3 preprints of my research work so far that I have put on arxiv, and (ii) my 2 industry internships and 1 lab experience (iii) my grades and relevant classes.

I have received very few scholarships since I did not really need any financial assistance and did not apply. So there isn't really much content. I'm considering doing a bullet point list to provide detailed description for each of internships and research projects but none of the professional academic CVs I have seen have done this. Would this be a good idea? What else can I put on CV as a PhD applicants.

Comment: StackExchange answers if you have a significant amount of well-regarded ones; contests if you have taken prizes in some (this includes problem sections of journals); undergrad seminar talks if you've given any; software if you have developed any (may not be field-specific, but if programming is useful in the field, your skills will speak for you).

Comment: Answer here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/137289/phd-program-application-cv-3-pages-versus-resume-1-2-pages-in-the-us/137351#137351